# How do you organize the fields in grails 2.4.4 including the static mapping relations?

Tags: grails, static, mapping, field, reorganize

Okay, so I understand how to organize the fields in grails without using the gsp pages by writing the fields in the constraints like so.

```
    Class User{
        String firstName;
        String nickName;

        static constraints = {} 
    }
```

this will make first name appear before nick name in the default scaffolding because f comes before n in the alphabet.

```
    Class User{
        String firstName;
        String nickName;

        static constraints = {
           nickName()
           firstName()
        } 
    }
```

this makes nick name appear before first name in the CRUD model in scaffolding. It's the order you name the constraints.

Now, how do you make the relations appear in a specific order? For example if I had this

```
    Class User{
        String firstName;
        String nickName;

        static belongsTo = {company:Company}

        static constraints = {

        } 
    }
```

How would I rearrange this order? would it be done in constraints? I know it can be done in gsp page, but how would I do it here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's the same as regular fields...

i.e. if you want the order of the fields to appear as `nickName`, `firstName`, `company` you'd do this:

```
Class User {
    String firstName
    String nickName

    static belongsTo = {company: Company}

    static constraints = {
        nickName()
        firstName()
        company()
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you have to do that and then re-generate the controller. That was messing with me.